# Printing Comments with PDF

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader

Is there a way to print the comments that are associated with a pdf on the linux version of Adobe Acrobat 9? Both acroread and evince *display* the comments just fine, however the linux version of the reader lacks the button in the print dialogue to enable printing comments.

Specifically I'm looking to recreate this feature (image taken from adobe.com) where the comments are printed on a seperate page with lines to the main document indicating where the comment was inserted.

[image]

Please Note: I am not asking to modify or write comments and annotations (typically a feature associated with Acrobat Pro), but to merely print them in a conveniently readable way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to click `Summarize Comments` button at the bottom of `File > Print` screen.

Comment: This button doesn't exist in the version of adobe acrobat that is in the ubuntu repo's